# Gnuplot Error Message: undefined variable via

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to fit some data using gnuplot.

```
f(x)=a*x+b
fit f(x) 'data.txt' via a,b
```

but it stops with `undefined variable: via` error. 
What should I do?

Comment: The commands you show are correct.  The fit might terminate with an error if the starting values for a and b are too far from the true values, but the error you show does not make sense.

Comment: @Ethan, is the command `using Colum1:Column2` not missing? Please @picard specify the column to feed in the fitting and let us know. Alternatively, you can share some data with us.

Comment: @many, if you don't specify anything gnuplot automatically takes column1 and column2. if there is only one column gnuplot takes column0 as x and column1 as y (see `help pseudocolumns`).

Comment: I can reproduce your error when typing `fit f(x) via a,b`, i.e. missing `'data.txt'`. Are you using this gnuplot script in the gnuplot console or maybe within another script where a variable should contain `'data.txt'` but is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fit f(x) 'data.txt'using 1:2 via a,b
```

whether your `x-axis` is the column `1` and your `y-axis` the column `2` of your datafile `data.txt`.

Gnuplot offers a very great assistance on the subject with the `help` command.

```
 help fit
```

I hope that help.

Comment: It stops with `undefined variable: using`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Note, that there is a little difference between the characters ``` `` ``` (I don't even know how to produce a single one here on SO)  and `'`, but it will make a big difference.

```
fit f(x) `data.txt` via a,b
```

will most likely reproduce your error message.

Whereas

```
fit f(x) 'data.txt' via a,b
```

or

```
fit f(x) "data.txt" via a,b
```

will probably fit your data.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but `undefined variable: via` error occurred with `'data.txt'` and `"data.txt"`.

Comment: are you typing this in the gnuplot console or do you send this via another script to gnuplot?

Comment: I'm using the gnuplot console (gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 8 - console version).

Comment: very strange. Are you sure you're typing single quotes instead of backquotes? Maybe some strange local language settings forcing it to backquotes?

Comment: @picard, I know how sensitive are (research) data but it may worth sharing a relevant sample with us?